# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having problems to update-database my classes into the database.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Sale_Service_Service_ServiceId' on table 'Sale_Service' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

**ENTITIES**

```
public class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }  
    public IList<ProductSale> Products { get; set; }
    public IList<SaleService> Services { get; set; }

    public Sale()
    {
        Products = new List<ProductSale>();
        Services = new List<SaleService>();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public float Duration { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<ServiceProfessional> Professionais { get; set; }
    public IList<SaleService> Sales { get; set; }
    public IList<ScheduleService> Schedules { get; set; }

    public Service()
    {
        Professionais = new List<ServiceProfessional>();
        Sales = new List<SaleService>();
        Schedules = new List<ScheduleService>();
    }

}


   public class SaleService
{
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

**MAPPINGS**

```
public class SaleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Sale>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Sale> builder)
    {

        builder.ToTable("Sale");

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.StartDate)
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.EndDate)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}



public class ServiceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Service>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Service> builder)
    {

        builder.ToTable("Service");

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Price)
            .HasColumnType("money")
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Duration)
            .IsRequired();

    }

}

  public class SaleServiceConfiguration:IEntityTypeConfiguration<SaleService>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SaleService> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Sale_Service");

        builder.HasKey(c => new {c.ServiceId, c.SaleId});
    }
}
```

**PART OF THE SCRIPT**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Sale_Service",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ServiceId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        SaleId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Sale_Service", x => new { x.ServiceId, x.SaleId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Sale_Service_Sale_SaleId",
            column: x => x.SaleId,
            principalTable: "Sale",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Sale_Service_Service_ServiceId",
            column: x => x.ServiceId,
            principalTable: "Service",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

Comment: What that message generally means is that you have a recursive reference, i.e., table A has a property b for table B, and table B has a similar property a for table A. Based on your code, my guess is that your SalesService class has a Service FK, and your Service class has a list of SalesService.

Comment: Yes, It has, you can see there that SalesService has a ServiceId which is the FK, and Service has a list of SalesService, the same rule for Sale class.

For me, it sounds ok. it's a many to many relationship.

But I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: That is the problem, and it can manifest itself in multiple ways. Let's say you delete record A, which in turn deletes child record B, which in turn tries to delete 'child' record A. You get similar troubles trying to serialize to JSON, where these records reference each other, and the object just recurses forever. There are lots of solutions, but does the problem make sense, first?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but as far as I know, that would be the way of representing a many-to-many relationship in entity frame work core 2

Comment: I honestly can't speak to Core, but EF6 in .NET 4.5+, threw the same fit. You need(ed) to get past the idea that FKs need to be explicitly defined. EF does that for you. Again, you can solve this in numerous ways. I can look for solutions for you later tonight, if you haven't figured this out; I don't have enough time right now to test my old solutions in Core. Sorry, that's not the best answer, but I'm off in a bit. :( But I'm confident that circular reference is your problem.

Comment: Alright, I'll be trying to solve it, thanks for your time.

Comment: A join table is good when you want to have many to many relatoinship. [student course example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: It is a many to many

Comment: I found the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

The problem was with the Category, both of them had a foreign key to the same table with a delete cascade, thus, if I deleted a category, the following tables will be affected.

*Sale*,
*Service*

And most important , *SaleService* (Join table)

My solution was very simple, I just created a category for each one.

SaleCategory and ServiceCategory.